# Stanford Parser - amod and nsubj dependencies - combinations of predicative and attributive adjectives

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

Having looked at the "Stanford typed dependencies manual", I understand to some extent how the amod and nsubj dependencies function from the following examples:

"Sam eats read meat"        amod(meat, red)

“The baby is cute”      nsubj(cute, baby)

I am assuming then that it would treat slightly more complex examples as follows:

"Sam eats meat that is red and tasty"   nsubj(meat, red), nsubj(meat, tasty)

"Red meat is tasty"                 amod(meat, red), nsubj(tasty, meat)

Have I understood this correctly?

If so, I wonder if I have also correctly understood how the parser would treat these examples from my own research:

"Vous ferez un vers baroque" amod(baroque, vers)

"Vous trouvez des vers plus baroques, plus durs, plus rocailleux que ceux-ci"   amod(baroque, vers), amod(dur, vers), amod(rocailleux, vers)

"Les beaux vers de Monsieur Racine sont durs et baroques" nsubj(baroque, vers), nsubj(dur, vers), amod(beau,vers)

I apologize if these are naive questions. I am an art historian attempting to use computational linguistics tools for my research on eighteenth-century art criticism. I also apologize if this is the wrong forum for this type of question.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you may be able to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a linguistics expert, but I should note that the parser is now creating Universal Dependencies, so you should consult this guide:

https://universaldependencies.org/u/overview/syntax.html

Furthermore, given that the parser is statistical, it may make errors from time to time.

Also, you can search through the French treebank (available at the universal dependencies web site) to see specific examples of French dependency trees used to train the parser. You could review some specific examples.